# How can I copy a config file to an AWS EB deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up a Node.js / express app and I am using `aws eb` to deploy.

[image]

That is how my config is set up to be environment specific. However, I don't want to put my `config.prod.json` in my source control. How can I get that put up to my deployed application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **.ebextensions** folder to add some commands to copy additional files from anywhere. More info:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Comment: It took me a while to find this in the AWS docs for Linux:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html
 See the section on "Files": "You can use the files key to create files on the EC2 instance. The content can be either inline in the configuration file, or the content can be pulled from a URL."